# Android Custom StopWatch Class

Tags: android

I have these codes within my listview row.In my custom listview adapter I have getView method and I start stopwatch from this method. I want to start a stopwatch for each row individually but only first one starts and others don't start. How can I fix this?

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private long startTime;
private long stopTime;
private long elapsedTime;
private final int REFRESH_RATE = 100;
private String hours,minutes,seconds,milliseconds;
private long secs,mins,hrs,msecs;
private boolean stopped = false;

public void startClick (View view){
    showStopButton();
    if(stopped){
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - elapsedTime; 
    }
    else{
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(startTimer);
    mHandler.postDelayed(startTimer, 0);
}

public void stopClick (View view){
    hideStopButton();
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(startTimer);
    stopped = true;
}

public void resetClick (View view){
    stopped = false;
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer)).setText("00:00:00");
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.timerMs)).setText(".0");   
}

private Runnable startTimer = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
           updateTimer(elapsedTime);
           mHandler.postDelayed(this,REFRESH_RATE);
       }
    };

private void updateTimer (float time){
    secs = (long)(time/1000);
    mins = (long)((time/1000)/60);
    hrs = (long)(((time/1000)/60)/60);

    /* Convert the seconds to String 
     * and format to ensure it has
     * a leading zero when required
     */
    secs = secs % 60;
    seconds=String.valueOf(secs);
    if(secs == 0){
        seconds = "00";
    }
    if(secs <10 && secs > 0){
        seconds = "0"+seconds;
    }

    /* Convert the minutes to String and format the String */

    mins = mins % 60;
    minutes=String.valueOf(mins);
    if(mins == 0){
        minutes = "00";
    }
    if(mins <10 && mins > 0){
        minutes = "0"+minutes;
    }

    /* Convert the hours to String and format the String */

    hours=String.valueOf(hrs);
    if(hrs == 0){
        hours = "00";
    }
    if(hrs <10 && hrs > 0){
        hours = "0"+hours;
    }

    /* Although we are not using milliseconds on the timer in this example
     * I included the code in the event that you wanted to include it on your own
     */
    milliseconds = String.valueOf((long)time);
    if(milliseconds.length()==2){
        milliseconds = "0"+milliseconds;
    }
    if(milliseconds.length()<=1){
        milliseconds = "00";
    }
    milliseconds = milliseconds.substring(milliseconds.length()-3, milliseconds.length()-2);

    /* Setting the timer text to the elapsed time */
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer)).setText(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.timerMs)).setText("." + milliseconds);
}
```